# Acronym capitalization not working in plural mode

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization

I am using the `glossaries` package to manage acronyms and it seems like the combination of "use long form", "make first letter uppercase" and "use plural form" does not work (see MWP below):

At first I thought it might be related to the remarks in the glossaries documentation concerning the uppercase commands not being expandable as I came across this problem when using `\Acfp` at the beginning of a caption in combination with `hyperref`. But even after removing all the clutter, it still does not seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newacronym{mTA}{mTA}{my test acronym}

\begin{document}
Try acr shortcuts:\\
\acf{mTA}\\
\Acf{mTA}\\
\acfp{mTA}\\
\Acfp{mTA}\\

Try acr commands:\\
\acrfull{mTA}\\
\Acrfull{mTA}\\
\acrfullpl{mTA}\\
\Acrfullpl{mTA}\\

Try gls commands:\\
\glsentryfirst{mTA}\\
\Glsentryfirst{mTA}\\
\glsentryfirstplural{mTA}\\
\Glsentryfirstplural{mTA}\\
\end{document}
```

[image: MWP]

The `\glsentryfirst*` family does the 'right' thing but are lacking the `hyperref` information (not part of the MWP).

So am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug. I'll get it fixed in the next version. For now, a simple workaround is to use one of the new acronym styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{mTA}{mTA}{my test acronym}

\begin{document}
Try acr shortcuts:\\
\acf{mTA}\\
\Acf{mTA}\\
\acfp{mTA}\\
\Acfp{mTA}\\

Try acr commands:\\
\acrfull{mTA}\\
\Acrfull{mTA}\\
\acrfullpl{mTA}\\
\Acrfullpl{mTA}\\

Try gls commands:\\
\glsentryfirst{mTA}\\
\Glsentryfirst{mTA}\\
\glsentryfirstplural{mTA}\\
\Glsentryfirstplural{mTA}\\
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of result]

Comment: I am wondering why the \glsentryfirst* commands have a different behavior when using the long-short format? Shouldn't they print 'long (short)' as well?

Comment: No. If you use `\setacronymstyle` the `first`, `firstplural`, `text` and `plural` keys aren't used by `\gls`. The purpose of the new acronym styles is to provide a far more flexible approach than the default glossary mechanism allows (which is why you have to explicitly activate the new acronym styles using `\setacronymstyle`). This is mentioned in the [changing the acronym style section](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:setacronymstyle) of the user manual.